# Unsatisfiable error in installing mysql in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python-3.x, database, package, mysql-python, anaconda3

I am trying to installing MySQL in Anaconda. But it is showing error in installing the following packages:
1. mysql-python-connector
2. mysql-python
Anaconda shows the following error:
'''
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- mysql-connector-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
- mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package setuptools conflicts for:
mysql-connector-python -> protobuf[version='>=3.0.0'] -> setuptools
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools

Package mysql-connector-c conflicts for:
mysql-python -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0']
mysql-connector-python -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0']

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
mysql-python -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates

'''